# Can I import data into Amazon Canvas through an API?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Is there any way to import a dataset into Sagemaker Canvas through APIs? I see that there are three  methods to do an import: upload a csv, connect to Redshift, S3 or snowflake.

So far, I am unable to find a way to import dataset through APIs and was hoping to get some answers here.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to import a dataset into Sagemaker Canvas through APIs. AWS Sagemaker provides a set of APIs for importing and managing datasets for use in the notebook environment. You can use the CreateDataset API to import data from a file in Amazon S3, or from an Amazon Redshift cluster. You can also use the UpdateDataset API to add or update data. Finally, the DeleteDataset API can be used to delete a dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Canvas support data from upload csv, redshift,s3 and snowflake. We can write a Job which downloads data from API and writes to s3 or redshift and then use it with Canvas.